# Issues with passing arguments to the print function in Java

Tags: java, swing, printing

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page, String customer_name) 
    throws PrinterException {

    System.out.println("The value of customer name:"+customer_name);

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    String x = layout.get("");
    System.out.println("The value of x is\n"+x);
    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    g.drawString("Customer Name: "+customer_names, 100, 100);


    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I want to call this method from another class, while passing an additional argument to it, `customer_name`. I call this method from another class as follow:

```
Printer print = new Printer();  //making an object to access that class Printer.java
PageFormat page = job.defaultPage();
print.print(<I have no idea what to put here for graphics>, page, 5, customer_name_field.getText());
```

When I call the method `print.print`, I gives the message that it requires `Graphics, PageFormat, int, String`. But what should I put for `Graphics`, I have no idea?

Comment: Your question looks to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question, and if so, I think to best allow us to help you, you will want to describe your overall goal, not how you are trying to wrongly achieve it with code. For instance, are you trying to print out a Swing GUI? If so, then the approach above is likely wrong. Are you trying to create your own Printable class? If so, I don't see that your print method will work as a true override, making your code not work, and possibly not compile.

Comment: My Goal is to pass the variable customer_name_field, what ever text that the user types in the JTextField in GUI, I want to send that variable to the printer class and use that variable in the print method. I don't know why it's not working. I am badly stuck.

Comment: It's not working because it looks like you're going about it wrong. If you just want to print some text then you need to follow the first sections of the [Printing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html). Your print method above does not conform with a Printable's `print(...)` method override. Please do yourself a favor and follow the tutorial. I've given you the link.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because it looks like you're going about it wrong:

- Your print method has an extra String parameter tacked to the end which prevents it from being a true method override for a class that implements Printable.
- You're trying to call your print method directly scrounging around for a Graphics context when you shouldn't consider doing this.

If you just want to print some text then you need to follow the first sections of the [Printing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html). Your print method above does not conform with a Printable's `print(...)` method override. Please do yourself a favor and follow the tutorial. I've given you the link.

Consider creating a class that implements Printable, passing your String as a **single** parameter to the class's constructor, and use this to set an instance field. The `print(...)` method should match that found in the tutorial, should have an `@Override` annotation, and most important **will never be called directly by you**. Your PrinterJob instance will do the printing behind the scenes.

Note, that if your goal is to print a Swing GUI, then the steps are different, since Swing GUI's carry much of the innate machinery for printing within them.

Comment: Hey, can i send you my code ? so you could have a look at it ? I am badly stuck, I don't know what to do

Comment: @Gugz_Singh: No, that's not how this site works, and you really should not be asking this. Again, I suggest that you read the tutorial and follow my suggestions. If still stuck, then ask a more complete question.

Comment: @gugz_singh You need to read through the tutorials that have bee provided in the answer. If you have a specific issue after trying something from the tutorials, the ask another question. We're not a coding service

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the class you're in, there's a high chance that the UI framework element you are currently using already provides you with the getGraphics() function.

You might even want to override the paint() function of the class you're using, and call this method you have written from that. It depends on your use-case.

Comment: Can I send you my code, to correct it ? I am really having issues with it and can't solve it

Comment: No, you should not directly call the print method that he's trying to create. This answer I'm afraid is way off the mark.

Comment: I assumed that what he wants is overriding an onPaint() function and then calling his own implementation from that function. It's fairly well-known that an onPaint() functionality in any UI element should not be directly called, but rather set it so the parameters are given, and invalidate() to make it so. I guess I didn't really understand what he was doing... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my github project path where i did  the code for same.    https://github.com/knikam/Mobile_shop_management/blob/master/src/mobile_shop_mangment/Sell_mobile.java

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) 
    throws PrinterException {



    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    String x = layout.get("");
    System.out.println("The value of x is\n"+x);
    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    String customer_namescustomer_names.getText();**This is work for me**
    g.drawString("Customer Name: "+customer_names, 100, 100);


    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```